# C# multiple select listbox selected item text

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, listbox-control

I have a list-box, I want to loop through all the selected items and get each selected items text value.

```
for (int i = 0; i < lstFieldNames.selectedItems.Count; i++)
{
string s = lstFieldNames.SelectedItems[i].ToString();
}
```

the value of s is "{ Item = ADDR }"

I don't need the { Item = }, I just want the text "ADDR".

What am I doing wrong, I tried a few things and nothing seems to work for me.

Comment: What's the datasource of the ListBox?

Comment: var items = (from i in xDoc.Descendants("ITEM") orderby i.Value select new {Item = i.Element("FIELDNAME").Value }).ToList(); l.DataSource = items; l.DisplayMember = "Item"

Comment: This is simply because the data type of items has no ToString() override (as it's created on the fly). There are two main options then AFAICS - 1) instead of using var items, create a holding class and pass the elements (or the collection as a whole) to the new class with the desired ToString override - 2) on the loop above, post process the selected item element by passing it to a function that returnms the item string and not the ToString.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this is a `Winforms` question because an `ASP.NET` ListBox has no `SelectedItems` property(notice the plural). This is important since a Winforms `ListBox` has no `ListItems` with `Text` and `Value` properties like in ASP.NET, instead it's just an `Object`.

You've also commented that the datasource of the `ListBox` is an anonymous type. You cannot cast it to a strong typed object later.

So my advice is to create a class with your desired properties:

```
class ListItem {
    public String Item { get; set; }
}
```

Create instances of it instead of using an anonymous type:

```
var items = (from i in xDoc.Descendants("ITEM") 
             orderby i.Value 
             select new ListItem(){ Item = i.Element("FIELDNAME").Value })
            .ToList();
```

Now this works:

```
foreach (ListItem i in lstFieldNames.SelectedItems)
{
    String item = i.Item;   
}
```

<sub>Note that my `ListItem` class is not the `ASP.NET` [`ListItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitem.aspx).</sub>

Comment: Thanks a million.  Once you directed me to the data source.. I seen where {Item =} was coming from.  All along I thought it was the listbox i was having problems with.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

```
string s = lstFieldNames.SelectedItems[i].Text.ToString();
```

Note the `Text` property

Comment: But this is a winforms question, in ASP.NET there's a Text property in `ListItem` but in Winforms it's just an object. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.selectedobjectcollection.item.aspx

Comment: I get an error when trying lstFieldNames.SelectedItems[i].Text;  'object' does not contain a definition for 'Text'

Answer (score 0):

This would fetch **Selected values only**.

**EDIT:**

```
foreach (object listItem in listBox1.SelectedItems)
{
    string s = listItem.ToString();
}
```

Comment: do i need to add a directive?  I get the error message - The type or namespace name "ListItem" could not be found(are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 0):

Use this code :

```
  string s = "";

  foreach(var item in lstFieldNames.SelectedItems) 
  {
     s += item.ToString() + ",";
  }

  textBox1.Text = s;
```

If need on one selected item from your listbox try this cod :

```
  string s = "";

  foreach(var item in lstFieldNames.SelectedItems) 
  {
     s = item.ToString();
  }
```

EDIT :

Try this one code

```
    private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string s = "";

        foreach (var item in listBox1.SelectedItems)
        {
            s += item.ToString() + ",";
        }

        textBox1.Text = s;
    }
```

Comment: nope this is not working either. I get an error - Unable to cast object of type'<>f_AnonymousType0'1[System.String]' to type 'System.String'

Comment: No error, but now i'm back to the original question.  it returns "{ item = ADDR }"